# 'TestController.Post()': not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am returning `HttpResponseMessage`, but still my code complains and throw below error,

> 'TestController.Post()': not all code paths return a value

What to return here?

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
    {
        var response = await IsDataValid();
        if (response)
            return Ok(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add just few more line of code to deal with the above error.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
{
    var response = await IsDataValid();
    if (response)
        return Ok(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK));
    else
        return NotFound();
}
```

The else part is important here.

Answer (score 1):

If within `ApiController`,  no need to return `HttpResponseMessage` if returning `IHttpActionResult`. Use the controller's helper methods.

For example

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post() {
    var response = await IsDataValid();
    if (response)
        return Ok();

    return BadRequest();
}
```